# $\prod_{j=1}^\infty A_j$ is uncountable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Let $A_j,j\in\mathbb Z^+$ be finite sets with at least two distinct elements.

How to show that $\prod_{j=1}^\infty A_j$ is uncountable?

Comment: One way is to use $2^{{\aleph}_0}=\aleph_1$.

Comment: @Ehsan: No way uses this assumption. At all.

Comment: Dear @Asaf why? what's wrong with it?

Comment: @Ehsan, it is simply irrelevant to the problem. $2^{\aleph_0}$ is **always** uncountable, regardless to the continuum hypothesis, or even the axiom of choice. Showing something is uncountable you don't have to calculate its exact cardinality, just show that there is one cardinality it is not -- $\aleph_0$.

Comment: @Asaf: I'm not getting what you mean. It simply right in track. You have used this fact implicitly in what you wrote as a solution.

Comment: @Ehsan: I have not. And that is something you can be sure of. I'll be happy to point out where you are wrong, if you will point out where I have made this implicit assumption.

Comment: @Asaf: perhaps, writing $\aleph_1$ is you problem and my only intention was to say that $2^{\aleph_0}$ in uncountable, nothing more. I think we're arguing in a different language over something we agree on.

Comment: @Ehsan: There is only one language to set theory. As I said, $2^{\aleph_0}$ is *always* uncountable. You don't need to use the continuum hypothesis or any other cardinal arithmetics. You don't even have to use the axiom of choice.

Comment: @Ehsan: $\aleph_1$ doesn't just mean 'uncountable', it means 'the smallest uncountable cardinal'. It's certainly true that $\aleph_1 \le 2^{\aleph_0}$, which is to say that $2^{\aleph_0}$ is uncountable, but putting the $=$ sign there is simply erroneous unless you adopt the continuum hypothesis as one of your axioms. But that's unnecessary here. If you were just trying to say "use the fact that $2^{\aleph_0}$ is uncountable" then that's what you should have said.

Comment: Dear @Clive: right! no need to use AC :)

Comment: @Ehsan: Actually by saying $\aleph_1\leq2^{\aleph_0}$ we do use AC.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

Replace each $A_j$ by $B_j=\{0,\ldots,n-1\}$, where $n=|A_j|$, using the axiom of choice. Now we have:
$$\left|\prod_{j\in\Bbb N}\{0,1\}\right|\leq\left|\prod_{j\in\Bbb N}B_j\right|=\left|\prod_{j\in\Bbb N}A_j\right|.$$

You can bound this from the right by the product of copies of $\Bbb N$ and calculate the exact cardinality too. I am leaving the details for you.

Do note, the axiom of choice is essential and it is consistent that there are families of finite sets whose product is empty, and thus countable.

Answer (score 1):

Identify a subset of each set with {0,1} using AC, and map the corresponding subset of the product onto binary expansions of reals in the interval [0,1], hence uncountable.

Comment: Sets have at least two distinct elements, how do you identify each set with $\{0,1\}?$

Comment: You should be aware that mapping each binary string to the real number it represents in binary, is not a bijection. It is true that it only has a countable number of "overlaps" which can be shown as sufficient to conclude there is a bijection between the two sets; but itself is not a bijection. And while it is true that if you can map a set onto $[0,1]$ then that set was uncountable, it is still tempting to make the above mistake.

Comment: good point, thanks.